# How to check if user is authenticated before rendering page?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I'm using Next.js with redux and firebase auth.

What I'm trying to achieve is to check whether a user is logged in before being able to access some private pages.

I have created a component called `AdminLayout` which is wrapped around every private page. I get the `currentUser` as props using `mapStateToProps` but I'm not getting the value in the first run.

```
// admin-layout.component.jsx
// Imports

class AdminLayout extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.currentUser);
    // if (this.props.currentUser) {
    //   if (this.props.currentUser.currentUser.role != "admin") {
    //     Router.push("/admin/login");
    //   }
    // }
    // if (!this.props.currentUser) {
    //   Router.push("/admin/login");
    // }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
            // Irrelevant code here
            {this.props.children}
            // Irrelevant code here
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AdminLayout);
```

Any way to overcome this situation and allow only authenticated users to access the private pages?

Comment: But I'm using Next.js, so I don't use the react-router-dom

Comment: Ok. Then you can create a [private route hoc](https://jasonraimondi.com/posts/secure-a-next-js-application-with-jwt-and-a-private-route-higher-order-component/#add-a-_privateroute_-higher-order-component-hoc-to-secure-the-app-from-unauthorized-access) to check and proceed or redirect or do it each [page / component level](https://github.com/iaincollins/nextjs-starter/issues/12#issuecomment-281728520).